# How can I use lighting to show that my shape is 3D?

Tags: java, swing, java-3d

I am working on my class project in java3D and I have run into an issue. I need to give my shape a material so that the light can show shadows, thus making the shape actually look 3D. Right now I have everything I need to display the shape, but I don't like the solid white color that it has, and I would like to make it so that the light object actually shows reflection on the shape. How can I go about doing this? I will add a picture of the current object at the bottom. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
    new MainFrame(new Assignment7(), 640, 480);
}

public void init() {
    // create canvas
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
    Canvas3D cv = new Canvas3D(gc);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(cv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    BranchGroup bg = createBranchGraph();
    bg.compile();
    SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse(cv);
    su.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    TransformGroup tg = su.getViewingPlatform().getMultiTransformGroup().getTransformGroup(0);
    Transform3D tx = new Transform3D();
    tx.lookAt(new Point3d(0,.5,2), new Point3d(0,0,0), new Vector3d(0,1,0));
    tx.invert();
    tg.setTransform(tx);
    
    View view = su.getViewer().getView();
    //view.setProjectionPolicy(View.PARALLEL_PROJECTION);
    view.setFieldOfView(0.4*Math.PI);
    
    su.addBranchGraph(bg);
}

private BranchGroup createBranchGraph() {
    BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
    TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
    spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    root.addChild(spin);
    //object
    Appearance ap = new Appearance();
    PolygonAttributes pa = new PolygonAttributes();
    //pa.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
    pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
    Shape3D shape = new Shape3D(new Octahedron(), ap);
    ap.setMaterial(new Material());
    ap.setPolygonAttributes(new PolygonAttributes(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_FILL, PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE, 0));
    Material mat = new Material();
    mat.setLightingEnable(true);
    mat.setShininess(30);
    ap.setMaterial(mat);
    shape.setAppearance(ap);
    Shape3D bracket1 = new Shape3D(new bracket(), ap);
    Shape3D partition2 = new Shape3D(new partition2(), ap);
    Shape3D bracket2 = new Shape3D(new bracket2(), ap);
    Shape3D partition3 = new Shape3D(new partition3(), ap);
    Shape3D head = new Shape3D(new head(), ap);
    Shape3D claw = new Shape3D(new claw1(), ap);
    Shape3D claw2 = new Shape3D(new claw2(), ap);
    
    bracket1.setAppearance(ap);
    partition2.setAppearance(ap);
    bracket2.setAppearance(ap);
    partition3.setAppearance(ap);
    head.setAppearance(ap);
    claw.setAppearance(ap);
    claw2.setAppearance(ap);
    
    //transform
    Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
    tr.setScale(0.25);
    tr.setTranslation(new Vector3d(0, 0, 0));
    TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
    spin.addChild(tg);
    tg.addChild(shape);
    tg.addChild(bracket1);
    tg.addChild(partition2);
    tg.addChild(bracket2);
    tg.addChild(partition3);
    tg.addChild(head);
    tg.addChild(claw);
    tg.addChild(claw2);

    BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere();
    
    MouseRotate rt = new MouseRotate(spin);
    rt.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
    spin.addChild(rt);
    
    Background bg = new Background(0f, .5f, 1.0f);
    bg.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
    root.addChild(bg);
    
    //lighting
    AmbientLight light = new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(Color.white));
    light.setColor(new Color3f(Color.black));
    light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    root.addChild(light);
    
    PointLight pl = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.white), new Point3f(3f,3f,3f), new Point3f(1f,0f,0f));
    pl.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    root.addChild(pl);
    
    PointLight pl2 = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.black), new Point3f(3f,3f,3f), new Point3f(1f,0f,0f));
    pl2.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
    root.addChild(pl2);
    
    return root;
}
```

Here is what the current shape looks like (without lighting):

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned you need to give the shape a Material, but you also need to tell the material how the light works, at the moment you only specify shininess meaning the other aspects will use default values. You could instead use `Material mat = new Material(ambient emissive diffuse specular shininess);` and change the values to suit, for example maybe this will work `new Material(blue, black, blue, white, 60f);` See the [JavaDoc](https://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.1/javax/media/j3d/Material.html) and this page for some helpful info: http://www.java3d.org/appearance.html

Comment: (1-) How is this different than your last question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72094093/how-can-i-make-my-shape-show-on-the-canvas3d) ?. If you have progressed on the problem, then delete the last question so people don't spend time answering a question that has newer information. Keep all the information/suggestions in one place so everybody knows what has been suggested.

Comment: @sorifiend The correct JavaDoc is here: https://jogamp.org/deployment/java3d/1.6.0-final/javadoc/javax/media/j3d/Material.html Your link points to an obsolete version of Java3D.